# How to get different Google forms CSV download separators for questions and options?

Tags: csv, google-forms

In Google forms CSV download, in the US/UK/Ireland locale, options selected in multiple-response questions are separated by commas. But so are questions, so that makes the lines impossible to parse.
eg
Q1 could be a single-response, Q2 options could be these three:

    `This, that
    Those
    Theirs, them, and other`

In the CSV we might get

    `Q1, Q2
    Response1, Those, Theirs, them, and other`

which of course  looks like four responses to Q2 rather than 2.

HOWEVER in a European (Swedish) locale, the options are separated by semicolons, which is much easier to parse:

    `Q1,Q2
    Response1, Those; Theirs, them, and other`

SO: can we specify different separators and if so how?
I do not have programmatic access to the account, all I can get is a CSV download from the owner so I'm interested to see if there are settings I can ask them to use.

Details
Docs, Microsoft Windows.

I asked this question on the Google Forms community with no reply:
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/13554553?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### There is a solution

> I do not have programmatic access to the account, all I can get is a
> CSV download from the owner so I'm interested to see if **there are
> settings I can ask them to use**.

You just ask them to:

1. **Temporarily change** from the US/UK/Ireland locale to a European locale.
2. **Download** the CSV file
3. **Change back** to the US/UK/Ireland locale.
4. **Send you** the new CSV file.

After **you receive the file**, if you want to import it in a sheet adjust your locale accordingly, if not, **you are done**.

Answer (score 0):

Marikamitsos made me try once again - and I discovered that now the US and Ireland locales now use the semicolon as item delimiters. 
That's good, but it would have been helpful if that change had been flagged somewhere.
I don't know when it happened.